# Unrecognised character on Ubuntu server command line

Tags: command-line, ubuntu, keyboard, character

Im pretty new to Linux in general. Ive just been following this tutorial(http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free/) to set up a web server.

I was doing fine until I had to set up the web user permissions. The command I am trying to run is pretty simple

> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data
>   /var/www

However my issue is whenever I type the :(colon) I always see a grey square on the command line as if to say the character im typing is not being recognised. This seems to happen with a lot of the special characters/ symbols eg @, {, }, ; etc etc

I think it might be my keyboard layout setup? Not sure though. If it is does anyone know how I can fix this.

The OS im experimenting with is ubuntu server 10.10

--->EDIT

I think it is my keyboard layout. When I press the shift and > key it seems to insert the :(colon) character just fine. Does anyone know how to change this to UK keyboard.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What terminal are you using. Konsole, gnome-terminal, etc?  What is the locale, the output of `locale`?  Or, is this input happening on the console?

Comment: Its the gnome-terminal. Im not sure what the locale is. Ermm is their a way to check? Apologies, I know this sounds noob-ish

Comment: type `locale` and enter.

Comment: wow now I feel stupid lol. I also googled and reset the locales using: sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

The locale stuff is GB.UTF-8 for everything apart from the LC_ALL which has nothing after the = sign. ANy ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the System Menu, select Keyboard to open the Keyboard Preferences. Click the Layouts tab to view the current layout and then either Add or select a different layout.

There's a useful 'Type to test settings' box at the bottom of the screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid but where is this system menu. On boot up im automatically taken to the command line. Thanks

Comment: Previously you said "gnome-terminal".   The above answer should work assuming you do have a UK keyboard to start with--does it work in Windows?. Otherwise it might be necessary to configure things key-by-key for those keys needing change.  Also see [sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow console-setup](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=372189) for the Linux console(no X11, Gnome or KDE.) [More: LocaleConf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LocaleConf)

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were running the Ubuntu desktop edition. For Ubuntu Server follow Frayser's comment above for reconfiguring X and you should be fine.

Comment: its my fault for saying gnome-terminal, sorry. Thank you all. I will try the above, fingers crossed :)

Comment: Thanks for the dpkg-reconfigure link Frayser. For anyone else reading I just ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow console-setup and went through the setup. All seems to be fine now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

It's very annoying in sever interface dealing with invalid Character. Who have not yet configured their keyboard problem try this. Use the layout of your residing country. Suppose English for AMERICAN,AUSTRALIAN. Hope this will work

sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration